# Unity 2D:Change the gravity scale of my player when I press a certain key?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm fairly new to unity and C# and I'm trying to understand how to change the gravity scale of my character when I press the space bar. When I debug it, it says that `Rigidbody2D.gravityScale` cannot be used as a method. Can someone explain why it brings this error and how to fix it?

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public float moveSpeed;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    public float addGrav;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        //Understanding::: If key pressed down, 
        //Transform - method that manipulates position of object
        //Translate moves transform in direction/distance of translation.
        //transform.Translate(translation);
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow)) 
        {
            transform.Translate (Vector2.up * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.DownArrow)) 
        {
            transform.Translate (Vector2.down * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow)) 
        {
            transform.Translate (Vector2.left * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow)) 
        {
            transform.Translate (Vector2.right * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.Space))
        {
            rb2d.gravityScale (addGrav);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

rb2d.gravityScale is not a method, it's a field that you can assign value to.

use this

```
rb2d.gravityScale = addGrav; //to asign
//other example
rb2d.gravityScale += addGrav; //to add
rb2d.gravityScale -= addGrav; //to substract
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because the compiler were reading it as a method since you used parentheses instead of equal sign. it should be like so.

> rb2d.gravityScale = addGrav;